# Why inserting empty struct to reserved vector increases memory?

Tags: c++, string, memory

**EDITED**
The code was compiled with `Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86` in VS2010 as 32bit and runs on Win7 64bit machine.

Program with empty `main` body takes 1KB of memory.

The `sizeof(Bag)=32`. (=16 bytes of internal buffer for short strings + 4 byte of pointer to memory if string bigger than 16 bytes is added + other internal stuff of string).

After reserving 200,000 elements the vector `v` takes 6400KB of memory. Thus, total memory until now is 7400KB.

What I don't understand is why after inserting 100,000 elements (which is smaller than reserved capacity of `v`) into `v` the memory usage increases to 14,800KB. If I replace `string` with `int` so the total usage memory will be as it supposed to be 1,800KB (= 1000KB + 200*4B)

```
1.    struct Bag
2.    {
3.       string s;      
4.    };

5.    vector<Bag> v;
6.    v.reserve(200000);

7.    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
8.    {
9.      v.push_back(Bag());
10.   }
```

Comment: How are you verifying the memory usage?

Comment: With `Task Manager`. I know that maybe this is not the most accurate tool, but it show very deterministic memory behavior on various machines (with same architecture of course).

Comment: Are you running with full optimizations so no unnecessary copies will be made?  Can you try replacing the `push_back()` calls with a single `resize(100000)`?

Comment: In task manager which "memory usage" are you looking at? Also, are you compiling in debug mode or release mode? There could be debug build only members etc.

Comment: @Brandon, you are right! I didn't notice that I was running in Debug:( Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

A `std::string` contains an additional allocated memory component to contain the contents of the string; the actual string object itself is only half the story. Some implementations have an optimization to eliminate the extra overhead for very short strings, but this is not guaranteed.

The amount of memory used by each allocation will depend on the minimum allocation characteristics for your platform.

Comment: That's why sizeof(Bag)=32. (= 16 bytes of internal buffer in string + other 16 for pointer and other stuff). So, when I reserve 200,000 of 32 bytes and then adds 100,000 `Bag`s no allocation in string should occur because empty string will stored in internal buffer. So what is allocated when adding `Bag` is added to vector?

Comment: @theateist I can't say without looking at the particular implementation of `std::string` that you're using. You haven't even mentioned which compiler you have.

Comment: I updated my post. The compiler is `Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86`

Answer (score 0):

`reserve()` function allocates memory for the bundle of Bag objects. This chunk of memory contains space for all data members of `std::string`. `std::string` allocates memory for keeping string data and has pointer to it as data member. The memory chunks for `std::string` data is addition space you observed.
In case of `int` data members: it has no additional buffers so there is no extra memory allocated.

The following snippet shows that string has extra bytes allocated:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
        std::string s;
        std::cout << "[1] Buf: " << s.capacity() << std::endl;
        s = "Now it's contain some data";
        std::cout << "[2] Buf: " << s.capacity() << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
./a.out
[1] Buf: 22
[2] Buf: 47
```

Comment: see my comment to @Mark. The string has 16 bytes of internal memory in stack. No allocation is made when adding `Bag` to vector

Comment: I know that it will grow because the new string is 26 bytes length which is **greater** then the length of the internal buffer of the string(in my case its 16) and that's why it allocated space in heap. But, I insert **empty** string into vector whose length is **smaller** than 16, so it shouldn't allocate nothing!

Comment: @theateist Please check capacity() function meaning. It's not related to the space where string object resided itself.